# How can I find PostgreSQL's storing&deleting algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, postgresql, hex

I have a question about PostgreSQL's data storing&deleting algorithm.

If I create table like below.
'test (i int, c char(10), birth date)'
And inserted some data like below. and some record deleted.
(123, 'abc', '2000-01-01'),(456, 'def','2001-01-01'). .......

And I looking into that table file using Hexa editor.
I find some pattern of storing, and deleting mechanism.
But I found that pattern&mechanism is not 100% Perfect.

I want to know storing & deleting algorithm.
(I'm already read many article and pdf,ppt from googling, sharedslide, etc)

Please tell me, Perfect algorithm & mechanism.
Thank you.

Comment: Download the source code from postgres.org and peruse it to find your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could write a book (quite a big book) on this topic.

Read the source code:

https://github.com/postgres/postgres/tree/master/src/backend

and developer information:

- https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Development_information
- https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Developer_FAQ
- http://www.postgresql.org/developer/

and manual:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc-intro.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage.html

Comment: Thank you, Craig. And if you know what files are related about that??? Find that file is so hard for me.

Comment: @SeonghwanKim That's why there are README files in the source tree, slides/talks/presentations about the structure, etc. There is not one file for the database structure. There are *many*. It is not a simple system. You should expect to spend many, many hours reading the code, probably weeks. Look at the `README` files in the subdirectories of `src/backend/storage` and `src/backend/access`. Read `heapam.c`, `smgr.c` and `md.c`. Read the development guidance linked above. Examine the heap structure with the `pageinspect` module. Read lots of comments.

Comment: It's like asking "where's the code in the Linux kernel that writes a file to disk?". There are hundreds of files involved.

Comment: Thank you, Craig. Very lots of help to me. Appreciate.

Comment: You need to read about WAL, MVCC, the heap structure, TOAST, tuple infomasks, TIDs (ctid etc), xmin/xmax, ....

Comment: Out of interest ... what are you trying to do? Why are you doing this?

Comment: I want to recovery deleted record. (using hex editor, manually). Thank you very much, Craig. see you again.